# Foreign Key as Primary Key when converting ER model to RDB

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship, rdbms

Hi guys I'm trying to implement database models using mysql.
One thing struck me when I was trying to convert E/R database model to Relational DB model. So here's the question.

*Please keep in mind that 'Relationship' from ERDB and 'Relation' from RDB are different.

As far as I know, the followings are the standard when converting ER entity sets and relationships to RDB relations.

```
Entity Sets
: Simply use all the attributes as columns (key attributes become the primary key).

Relationships (Many-Many)
: Use key attributes (from both entity sets) as table columns.
```

So this means that when I'm trying to create a table for any relationship, I have to bring the key(keys) from existing tables (like a foreign key).

But when I looked up, almost everyone told me I shouldn't use a referenced foreign key as a primary key for that table (because foreign keys should allow non-unique values). This doesn't make sense because all kinds of relationship have to reference the keys from entity sets (relations).

I'm totally confused, somebody please help me!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by ER? True Chen ER has explicit relationship types with all participations to entity types. (Which are possibly associative, ie reifications of relationship types). Ie there are no FKs in (non-associative) entity relations/tables. Whereas other (pseudo-)ER methods push many:1 relationship relations/tables into the many-side relation/table. In true ER terms this converts an entity into a relationship and reifies all relationships to associative entities. But true ER is an unnecessarily restrictive method that does not make proper use of the relational model anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with using foreign keys as primary keys and there's no rule saying foreign keys should allow non-unique values.

Some people prefer surrogate identifiers over composite keys, which tend to be composed from foreign keys. Some would argue that tables with a single foreign key as primary key can be denormalized into the referenced table. Together, these approaches could eliminate foreign keys as primary keys.

On the other hand, each surrogate identifier adds a meaningless level of indirection and enforces certain access paths (google "access path independence"). It's also not always a good idea to denormalize tables with the same primary key - they may be recording predicates with different lifetimes, and combining tables can require the introduction of nulls which add their own problems.

In short, using foreign keys as primary keys is a valid approach. Whether you do it or not, try to understand the consequences of your decision and don't just follow a rule blindly.

PS. Technically, we don't convert entity sets to relations. Entity sets are represented by entity keys which map to domains in the relational model. Entity relations are relations which map from entity sets to value sets. It's a subtle difference, but an important one in fact-oriented modeling. Tables/relations represent the extensions of predicates, and any number of predicates may describe a single entity set.

A more general rule for mapping relationships to relations is to use the keys of the entity sets in "many"-roles as primary key. This holds for binary one-to-many and many-to-many relationships, as well as for ternary and higher relationships. One-to-many relationships are commonly denormalized into an entity relation, but that's a physical model optimization in my view.

Comment: I read entity sets and value sets as domains. Would you mind pointing out specific sections of Chen's paper?

Comment: See the paragraph before 2.3.2 that contains "Each value in the value set EMPLOYEE-NO represents an entity", section 2.3.2, and compare figures 4 and 7. The latter represents an entity relation without the conceptual entity set column that was present in the former.

Comment: Your quote talks about representing information rather than representing entities, and I don't see how it supports your argument. Figure 4 distinguished an entity set from an entity relation, and figure 5 clearly shows entity sets in their roles in a relationship, to be represented by corresponding value sets in figure 8.

Comment: I've decided that I really don't know what you are trying to say in your PS. I don't understand what you mean by  "convert", "represent" or "map". (And apparently you sometimes say a set converts/maps to a thing when you mean each element converts/maps to a thing.) So I am not going to maintain any position except that your PS is not clear.  I hope my comments didn't make any unclear wordings of the kind I'm talking about. (PS I would say a table represents *the extension* (satisfying tuples) of a predicate in a given situation.)

Comment: I'm sorry that you deleted your comments - even though we could not come to an agreement, others could've benefited from comparing the different perspectives. I can, however, agree with your final PS.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use one of the foreign keys in a relationship table as the primary key of that table.  That would over constrain the table, because it would force the relationship between one of the entity tables and the relationship table to be one-to-one.  And that's not what you want.

However, there is no rule that says that you can't make the two foreign keys of a relationship table into a composite primary key.  If you haven't learned about composite primary keys (sometimes called compound primary keys) you should learn that.  Until you do, you will remain somewhat confused about the relational model itself.

As reaanb said, some database builders prefer to add a separate column to the relationship table to serve as a primary key.  But some just create a composite primary key.

Conversion of an ER model into a relational model is relatively mechanical, but non trivial.  And if you become good at both models, you may find it to your advantage to use the ER model for analysis of the subject matter and the relational model for database design.

Comment: Incidentally, I trace "foo bar" back to the Tech Model Railroad Club, circa 1961.